# add to cart in wordpress ecommerce in top and bottom product description

Tags: wordpress

I want to add button "Add to Cart" in top of product description page. Current this button shows in bottom of product description page.

Please suggest. I'm using latest wordpress 3.8.1 and "WP e-commerce 3.8.13.3" plugin.

Comment: Provide more details.

Comment: Selling online product through wordpress wp-ecommerce plugin. There are "add to cart" button on product description page on bottom. So visitor didn't see "add to cart" button immediately. They need to scroll complete page description for "Add to Cart" button. So I want "add to cart" button on "top description page" as well as "bottom description page".

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Copy the wpsc theme files into your theme (if you haven't already)

Go to **Settings**->**Store**->**Presentation**

Click **Move Template files**

**Step 2**

go to your theme folder and modify the file **wpsc-single_product.php**

Find the section `<div class="wpsc_buy_button_container">...</div>` and duplicate or move it wherever you need it.

Comment: Thanks Hannes, I did duplicate <div ...>...</div> but "Add to Cart" button is not "functional" only button shows.

Is any others code is required? Pls guide